# FOSJSROUTING The route "xxx" does not exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony, routes

Alright, there are plenty of posts about this, but I didn't make those errors... so let's go!

Im trying to send an ajax request and get a html response.

```
    function callModal(key) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: Routing.generate('behrens_edit_modal', {boxId: key}),
    })
        ...
}
```

and I had no issues with this code in the past. So that can't be it. Now for my controller:

```
    /**
 * @param $boxId
 * @return JsonResponse
 * @Route(path="/edit-box/{boxId}", name="behrens_edit_modal", options={"expose": true})
 */
public function FormAction($boxId)
{
...
}
```

But I just get the error saying:

```
router.js:9 Uncaught Error: The route "behrens_edit_modal" does not exist.
at K.f.i (router.js:9)
at K.f.m (router.js:10)
at callModal ((index):387)
at HTMLElement.onclick ((index):103)
```

Comment: and yes fosjsrouting is installed following all the steps. Composer, app kernel, routing.yml, publish asset and the <script> tag

Comment: Where you request to the route? from other javascript application or rendered it in Symfony app? `behrens_edit_modal` is just an alias that known in Symfony container.

Comment: Did you try clear cache?

Comment: It is used in the ajax function at the top. And no I haven't cleared my cache

Comment: clearing cache didnt help

Comment: Does FormAction Method is in the same controller which renders the view ?

Comment: The code for viewing the form might not work, problem is, it doesn't even get to the controller to render anything, it doesn't find the route for the controller, that's where it errors.